# Automatic Versions for Visual Studio on Web Page project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, .net-assembly, versioning

I have an old "web page" project in Visual Studio 2015 that I'm trying to add a version to.  I have created my AssemblyInfo.vb file under my App_Code folder and have the following inside it...

```
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

' General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
' set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
' associated with an assembly.

' Review the values of the assembly attributes

<Assembly: AssemblyTitle("MyWebSite")>
<Assembly: AssemblyDescription("")>
<Assembly: AssemblyCompany("")>
<Assembly: AssemblyProduct("MyWebSite")>
<Assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © MyCompany 2018")>
<Assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")>

<Assembly: ComVisible(False)>

' Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
'
'      Major Version
'      Minor Version 
'      Build Number
'      Revision
'
' You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
' by using the '*' as shown below:
' <Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")> 

<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.3.4")>
<Assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.2.3.4")>
```

On my website I have a Template.master that references...

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Version"></asp:Literal>
```

And on my website I also have a Template.master.vb that contains...

```
Dim assembly As Assembly = Assembly.Load("App_Code")
Dim ver As Version = assembly.GetName().Version
Version.Text = "Version: " + ver.Major.ToString() + "." + ver.Minor.ToString() + "." + ver.Revision.ToString() + " build (" + ver.Build.ToString() + ")"
```

Now when I build my site it looks exactly as I would expect with the following shown...

> Version: 1.2.4 build (3)

Now that I have all that setup I was hoping to get one of my favorite extensions in Visual Studio working to assist me in updating the version each build.  I have set it up so I have the following...
[image]

It looks good just like I have it set up in my other projects and I have confirmed the path to the assembly is 100% correct etc.

For some reason it will never update the versions when I build or publish the webpage.  Even the Automatic Versions logs are blank.  Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance it looks like the path is slightly off to the AssemblyInfo.  Since you're setting the value on the project level, the path is relative to the project, so I think you can just say .\App_Code\AssemblyInfo.vb.  Alternatively, I believe if the AssemblyInfo.vb project is in the "Properties" folder then you don't even have to specify the path.

Comment: I don't think putting it in a new folder called `Properties` is an option.  If the file is not in the `App_Code` folder it will not get compiled.  Let me try to see if the new path works though.

Comment: Yeah that could be based on the project type.  Also note there is a browse button next to that textbox that should do a good job of setting the relative path correctly for you.  If it doesn't then let me know, that might be a bug to address.

Comment: The solution seemed to be using that path!  It seems that when you use the big nice browse `...` button to the right, and choose the assembly info file it puts the path shown in my example images above.  But when I did what you suggested and manually changed the path to `.\App_Code\AssemblyInfo.vb` (noting the period at the start) it worked like a charm!  Thanks!

Comment: Ah ok good to know.  I'll get in a ticket to update the browse ... button fixed.